# Text in two lines of Equation

Tags: equations

I make a equation. But I want the words "Factor Mecânico de Filler" in two lines. "Factor Mecânico" in one line and "de Filler" in other line, for exemple. Is it possible ?

```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
        \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
        \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}

            \begin{equation}
            \label{equacao_}
            \text{Factor Mecânico de \textit{Filler}} = \frac{[\text{\% \textit{Filler} efectivo} \times \text{Índice de Tracção] (Modificado)}}{[\text{\% \textit{Filler} efectivo} \times \text{Índice de Tracção] (Original)}}
            \end{equation}

            \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suffice to put your text in a tabular environment (with no column separator). Or you can use the `stackengine` package and its `\Centerstack` command.

I also rewrote the right member in a fraction that looks better, in my opinion. Here is an illustration of both methods:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{equacao_}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} {Factor Mecânico} \\ de\textit{Filler}\end{tabular} = \frac{[\text{\% \textit{Filler} efectivo} \times \text{Índice de Tracção] (Modificado)}}{[\text{\% \textit{Filler} efectivo} \times \text{Índice de Tracção] \rlap{(Original)}\hphantom{(Modificado)}}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{equacao_}
\Centerstack{Factor Mecânico\\ de\textit{Filler}} = \frac{[\text{\% \textit{Filler} efectivo} \times \text{Índice de Tracção] (Modificado)}}{[\text{\% \textit{Filler} efectivo} \times \text{Índice de Tracção] \rlap{(Original)}\hphantom{(Modificado)}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]